# OpenJPA + Derby ManyToOne issue after update OpenJPA from 1.2 to 2.2

Tags: java, junit, derby, openjpa, many-to-one

I just updated OpenJPA from version 1.2 to 2.2 and many of my JUnits failed. Most of them because ManyToOne relation changed behavior. Lets say we have two entities

```
package org.my;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
public class Many {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private One one;

    public One getOne() {
        return one;
    }

    public void setOne(One one) {
        this.one = one;
    }

}
```

and

```
package org.my;

import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class One {
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "one")
    private List<Many> many;

    public List<Many> getMany() {
        return many;
    }

    public void setMany(List<Many> many) {
        this.many = many;
    }

}
```

When I Create One object and set to it List of Many, than persist and commit I got an exception like this

```
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.InvalidStateException: The field "one" of instance "org.my.Many@4d9cfefb" contained a null value; the metadata for this field specifies that nulls are illegal.
```

I thought that OpenJPA cat find One object and put it into Many.one field, am I wrong? If not how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Every **Many** object in the **List** of **One** object should be **setOne** first before you save it